# Connections between an identity about minors and Plücker relations

Tags: matrices, determinant, grassmannian

Consider a $2 \times 4$ matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 & d_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 & d_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Its all minors of order 2, such as $A_{13} = \begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & c_2 \\ \end{vmatrix}$ representing the minor formed by selecting the first and third columns, satisfy the following identity, which is easy to verify:
$$
A_{13}A_{24}=A_{12}A_{34}+A_{14}A_{23}
$$
And the identity holds in a more general situation, such as an $n \times m$ matrix where $m \geq n+2$. By selecting any fixed $n-2$ columns, and then selecting 4 distinct columns from the remaining ones using similar indices as described above, the identity still holds.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding), the form of the identity is the same as the Plücker relation in the case of $\mathbf{Gr}(2,4)$. From my professor, these two equations are indeed related in some sense, and I wonder where this connection comes from.

Furthermore, I'm seeking how to prove this identity without knowledge related to Grassmannian manifolds (as I know nearly nothing about it).

Comment: [This paper](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/27/tm1428.pdf) has a straightforward proof and a rough outline of the wider theory.